# Radio button size in android

Tags: android

How can I decrease the radio button size in android using java code? Its too big.

I'm using the code:

```
deal = new RadioButton(context);
deal.setHeight(10);
deal.setWidth(5);
```

which is not effective at all. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Are you creating radio button dynamically. Then instead of setting height and width using `setheight` and `setwidth` method you can use `layoutparams`. Set the width and height in `layout params`...given below is the example of setting parameters of the button..

```
addQuestion = new Button(NewEmirContext);

addQuestion.setId(134);
addQuestion.setTag("addQuestion");
addQuestion.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.add_button));
addQuestion.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams addQuestion_Params = 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(24, 24);  
addQuestion_Params.leftMargin=20;
addQuestion.setOnClickListener(mirScreenClickListener);
questionAndAddButtonContainer.addView(addQuestion, addQuestion_Params);
```

Comment: I use the param.topMargin=20; But It has no effect to change the gap between the radio buttons. Anything wrong? thanks.